# iphone mail and special characters

Tags: objective-c

In my iPhone app, I pass email content to the standalone iPhone mail app, but the content is  truncated when it contains special characters. It's the same even if I pre-process the content with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

Comment: Maybe list examples of those special characters so we can have a better idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` will not escape characters that are valid in a URL, such as `&`. In this case you need to escape them though because otherwise they would be interpreted as part of the URL's structure (indicating a new parameter) and not as part of the parameter itself. Use [`CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes) instead:

```
NSString *escaped = [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            (CFStringRef)someURLParameter,
                                            NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Percent escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) characters is only used in URLs.  It's not part of the [MIME spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Are you sure these are proper UTF-8 characters?!  So long as you're passing a string, Mail should package everything in an email itself.